# Swift iOS - Scroll view not scrolling properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, scrollview

I have got a textView and a scrollView. I want to achieve a state where I click in the textView and it will make way for the keyboard. However it seems to work only when I click on the textView for the second time.

And the code:

```
@objc open override func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    keyboardTapGesture.isEnabled = true

    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    let info = notification.userInfo!

    let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
    let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize?.height ?? 0.0, right: 0.0)

    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(commentInput.frame, animated: true)
}

@objc open override func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    keyboardTapGesture.isEnabled = false

    scrollView.contentInset = .zero
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero
    view.endEditing(true)
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might need another handling for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` too, as the keyboard frame can change during that time frame as well, especially with 3rd party keyboard

Comment: Right! For anyone stumbling onto this post, you need to either update the keyboard height with the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification or in some circumstances if the height is right for the first time you could to calculate the keyboard height when the keyboard first appears and keep hold of that, if you are not changing keyboard's dimensions.